# Confused about transformers' documentation

Tags: python-3.x, huggingface-transformers

I'm reading the documentation of the transformer's library from huggingface and I'm a bit confused about the BertModel's forward output.
It's stated in the documents that there are two outputs(and two optional ones) that are:

- last hidden state
- pooled output

and it's suggested in the documentation of the latter one that:

> This output is usually not a good summary of the semantic content of the input, you’re often better with averaging or pooling the sequence of hidden-states for the whole input sequence.

So, It sounds to me like the first output can be a better representation of the input's semantic. However, in the code for `BertForSequenceClassification` the second output is used and to feed the fully connected layer. Why is that?
This is a part of the code:

```
 pooled_output = outputs[1]
 pooled_output = self.dropout(pooled_output)
 logits = self.classifier(pooled_output)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this is largely a pointer towards ways of improving your model.
For rapid prototyping and faster training, the pooling method is definitely preferred, as it has a bit less computation and simpler to understand, and "proven track record" of performing well in classification tasks.

As far as I am aware, despite the comment in the documentation, I cannot recall any immediate results where the averaging of embeddings was way better than a simply pooling over the `[CLS]` token for a classification task. In my opinion the averaging would probably also make gradient propagation a bit more inconsistent, as the flow now divides through several heads instead of just the `[CLS]` one, potentially leading to a zeroing of the gradient for longer sequences (this is purely theoretical speculation, and I cannot back this up with actual results).

You are right that this is a bit inconsistent, and I was hoping they would offer a secondary model that might be doing it that way soon, but maybe this is your chance of contributing to open source ;-)